# Show react component given a condition

Tags: react.js, jsx

I want to show the battery icon given the `status` provided in props. I am trying to keep it simple but without writing too much code, i.e.: . `if ... else`, `switch`s statements...

Below code snippet works but it kinda looks forced, not sure.

```
import {
    TiBatteryLow,
    TiBatteryMid,
    TiBatteryHigh,
    TiBatteryFull
} from 'react-icons/ti'

const battery = {
    low: {
        color: "text-red-500",
        icon: TiBatteryLow
    },
    mid: {
        color: "text-yellow-400",
        icon: TiBatteryMid
    },
    high: {
        color: "text-green-400",
        icon: TiBatteryHigh
    },
    full: {
        color: "text-green-600",
        icon: TiBatteryFull
    }
};

export default function BalanceIndicator({status}) {
    let Balance = battery[status].icon;

    return (
        <div className="text-sm flex items-center">
            <i className={`mr-3 text-2xl ${battery[status].color}`}><Balance /></i>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps conditional rendering?

PS: In title, by condition I mean the value of `status`.

Comment: little code. It is nice. All by Fowler ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prefer `const` over `let`

The variable `Balance` is declared with `let`.

> ```
> let Balance = battery[status].icon;
> ```

It can be declared with `const` instead, since it is only assigned once. This can help avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).

### Reducing lookups

> ```
> let Balance = battery[status].icon;
>
> return (
>     <div className="text-sm flex items-center">
>         <i className={`mr-3 text-2xl ${battery[status].color}`}><Balance /></i>
>     </div>
> )
> ```

With this approach the icon is stored in `Balance` yet the color needs to be looked up again. The icon and color could be stored in variables after a single look-up with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
const {icon, color} = battery[status];

return (
    <div className="text-sm flex items-center">
        <i className={`mr-3 text-2xl color}`}><icon /></i>
    </div>
)
```

This makes the line containing the markup shorter, which improves readability.

### Error handling

What happens if `status` does not correspond to a key in `battery`? Perhaps it is unlikely but as code grows over time the likelihood could grow. The code should handle this scenario - perhaps with an error message or exception thrown.

Comment: Nice catch with destructuring!